# wcs1800 current sensor (with sensitivity of 66mV/A) output voltage varies unexpectedly with a range of 10 - 20mA

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, sensitivity, current-sensor

[image]I am using wcs1800 sensor to read current in the range of 100mA to 30A, even though the sensor has a sensitivity of ~66mV/A (5V input) and ~50mV/A (3.3v input) the output voltage is varied in the range of 10mA - 20mA which makes the sensor unusable to read the current in the range of 100mA. I have tried the recommended capacitor values for output from the [datasheet](http://www.winson.com.tw/Data%20Sheet/WCS1800.pdf). Can someone help me with a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We don't know enough about your circuit and your current waveform to answer this. Please include a schematic (there's a button on the editor toolbar) and details about the current waveform and how you are measuring the output voltage.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am just comparing the sensor characteristics with its datasheet to calibrate its reading for an ADC interface. And about the waveform, its DC am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting too much dynamic range from a crude Hall sensor like that. Thermal drift alone is 1mV/K which means 7 degrees C change will change the output equivalent to a 100mA current, so the variation you are seeing is equivalent to only a degree C or two.

Maybe you can use another sensor that covers a lower range (either more sensitive or wind more turns through the core). It will saturate at higher currents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if the variation is affected by the thermal drift it can be compensated by measuring the temperature and a properly coded controller. But the problem seems to continuously varying output (range of 10mV - 20mV) even without temperature variations I have used a capacitor, but no use.

Comment: Doubtful compensation can be effective enough, but even if it could be made perfect, there is specified output noise of 15mVp-p which corresponds to 25mA. There is doubtless some drift as well.

Comment: Can you please suggest a sensor with good dynamic range. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at LEM products (Swiss company). Not cheap though.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this somewhat by taking a very large amount of samples (500) separated by 10ms, and calculating the mean value. Variation in my readings is thereby limited to 0.05 A  (ca. 3mV from the WCS1800), which is usable for me.

Temperature drift is indeed around 1mV per Kelvin/Celsius, with the output increasing (suggesting more current is measured) as temperature drops.